# RxJava - Testing Single.zip() to ensure all arguments are executed

Tags: java, junit, mockito, rx-java, rx-java2

I'm trying to test that `Single.zip(...)` calls every argument even if one fails, however sometimes `verify` will fail because the test has finished executing before `Single.zip` has...

I feel like `await` should essentially be blocking but that doesn't always seem to be the case. Anything I'm missing?

Code:

```
public Completable execute(String id) {
    return doThing()
        .flatMap(result -> Single.zip(
            employeeService.getEmployee(id),
            databaseService.getData(id),
            (employee, data) -> ...
         ))
         .toCompletable();
}
```

Test:

```
@Test
public void test() {
    Exception ex = new Exception("err");

    when(employeeService.getEmployee(anyString()).thenReturn(Single.error(ex));

    myObject.execute("id")
     .test()
     .await()
     .assertFailure(e -> e.equals(ex);

    verify(employeeService).getEmployee(eq("id"));
    verify(databaseService).getData(eq("id"));
}
```

**Possible Solution**

```
  verify(employeeService, atLeast(0)).getEmployee(eq("id"));
  verify(employeeService, atMost(1)).getEmployee(eq("id"));
  verify(databaseService, atLeast(0)).getData(eq("id"));
  verify(databaseService, atMost(1)).getData(eq("id"));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm trying to test that Single.zip(...) calls every argument even if one fails, however sometimes verify will fail because the test has finished executing before Single.zip has...

This is hard to believe. I think your test is failing for some other reason.

```
Single.zip(
        employeeService.getEmployee(id),
        databaseService.getData(id),
        (employee, data) -> ...
```

When `Single.zip()` is called here, `employeeService.getEmployee(id)` and `databaseService.getData(id)` will be called even before control goes into `Single.zip()`.

The arguments to a method call are evaluated first even before the control goes into that method. So irrespective of what `Single.zip()` does both these methods will be called.

I think your test is failing because there is some other error in `doThing()` perhaps.

Comment: I think you're right, I just wrote a super simple test using `Single.zip()` and the verifications didn't fail, even after 10,000 executions. I shall investigate further, cheers!